# Definite integral involving modified Bessel function

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I'm trying to solve the following integrals:
$$
I:=\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}I_{0}\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)dx\quad II:=\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}I_{1}\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)dx
$$
where $I_{n}$ denotes the modified Bessel function of first kind.

**My question** : Is my answer finished and true?

**My answer** :
$$
I=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2k+1)2k\cdots(k+1)}{k!}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2k}
$$
$$
II=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)\cdots (k+2)}{k!}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2k+1}
$$

I wonder if I can get more simple form of solution but I don't know.
If there are some formula, I'm glad if you tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the first integral as $ \frac{8}{3 \sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Likewise, Wolfram Alpha gives the second integral as $\frac{4}{3 \sqrt{3}}$, exactly half of the first integral

Comment: I couldn't find the formula in Wolfram Alpha. Could you tell me the url?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+BesselI%5B1%2C+-%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B2%7D%5Dxe%5E%7B-x%7Ddx

Comment: We do know that $I_0(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{1}{4}z^2)^k}{(k!)^2}$... Maybe I can solve the first in terms of this. I'm trying to figure out what process WA uses

Comment: Thank you in advance. I also try to calculate more. Please tell me when you understand.

Comment: If my calculations are correct the first simplifies to solving $$ =  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{4^{-2 k} \Gamma(2k+2)}{(k!)^2}\bigg) $$
I feel like there must be a better way if WA solves it so fast, but I'll keep rolling (Not that I claim I did that right... I haven't double checked my work yet)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha confirmed that the summation is correct, so I will continue with that method. The question remains as to how to solve the second integral... I'll have to try something else for that one. Hey, knowing two ways to solve a problem isnt bad

Comment: Your solution is the same as my answer, doesn't it? Thank you in advance again.

Comment: The solution to the first integral is $\frac{8}{3\sqrt{3}}$.  I'm comparing my work to that, constructing a proof as I go along

Comment: I got the answer to $$ =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{ \Gamma(2k + 2)}{16^{k}\Gamma(k+1)^2}\bigg) $$
I'm going to come back to this after I try another method. Is there a time frame on this problem, or is it recreational? I have to sleep now, which is why I ask, although I can work more on the problem tomorrow.

Comment: It isn't recreational and it's in my research. I don't hurry especially but I'm glad early when I understand how to solve.

Answer (score 3):

There are way nicer closed forms, since:
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(I_0(x)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{s>1}(s),\qquad \mathcal{L}\left(I_0(x)\right) = -1+\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{s>1}(s)$$
and:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(x e^{-2x}\right) = \delta'(s-2),$$
hence the first integral equals:

> $$ I = 4\int_{0}^{+\infty}x e^{-2x} I_0(x)\,dx =4\cdot\left.\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\right|_{s=2}=\color{red}{\frac{8}{3\sqrt{3}}}$$

and the second integral equals:

> $$ II = -4\int_{0}^{+\infty}x e^{-2x} I_1(x)\,dx = -4\cdot\left.\frac{d}{ds}\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\right|_{s=2} = \color{red}{-\frac{4}{3\sqrt{3}}}.$$

Comment: I finally finished my proof with Mickep's help, but I missed the beauty of this transform. As is most of your work, beautifully done.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I'm sorry for my late reply. You told me your technique using Laplace transform but I forgot... Thank you again. When you get a chance, I'm glad if you think about [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459571/help-my-calculation-of-integral-to-verify).

Answer (score 1):

Now a full solution using Elementary methods (Thanks to Mickep for the advice)
$$I_n(z) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} e^{z\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)d\theta$$
$$I_0(-\frac{x}{2}) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} e^{-\frac{x}
{2}\cos\theta}d\theta $$
$$***$$
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}I_{0}\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}\int_0^{\pi} e^{-\frac{x}{2}\cos\theta}d\theta dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi} xe^{-x(\frac{\cos\theta}{2}+1)}d\theta dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{4}{(\cos\theta+2)^2} d\theta$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{8\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} = \color{red}{\frac{8}{3\sqrt{3}}}$$
$$***$$
We follow a similar process for the second integral
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}I_{1}\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}\int_0^{\pi} e^{-\frac{x}{2}\cos\theta}\cos\theta \,d\theta \,dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi} xe^{-x(\frac{\cos\theta}{2}+1)}\cos\theta \,d\theta \,dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{4\cos\theta}{(\cos\theta+2)^2} d\theta$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{4}{(\cos\theta+2)^2} d\theta$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{-4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} = \color{red}{\frac{-4}{3\sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: Just change order of integration, and use that $\int_0^{+\infty} x e^{-ax}\,dx=1/a^2$. Then, you have a "simple" integral of a rational function in $\cos \theta$ left.

Comment: @mickep Thanks for the hint! It seems obvious now, but I guess I was just too tired last night to notice that I could simply flip the integrals.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I'm sorry for my late reply. I can understand obediently your calculation. Thank you very much :)